# Is this some sort of fungus?

Tags: species-identification, mycology, growth

There is something strange growing straight out of the glass windows at work. They look like hairs, about half an inch long, and each have a white spot on the tip of them, slightly weighing them down. I first saw a few of them a week ago, and now there's about twice as many. They don't move, except when blown in the wind, etc.

Here's just a few of them, the first ones I discovered:

[image]

They haven't budged from this spot since I first discovered them, but more have appeared surrounding them. This is located in Louisville, KY, USA, and there has been some hot humid weather lately. This particular area where they're growing is in the shade and a partial roof, so these windows rarely ever get rained on.

A friend hinted that they might even be insect eggs.

What are these things? Fungus? If so, what kind?

Comment: Looks like a couple mold sporangia. I have no way of making an ID though.

Comment: @CMosychuk That makes sense (now that I look at pictures of them). Also since that area never gets any rain (but plenty of moisture in the air).

Comment: @CMosychuk But now that I look a bit more, I don't think so. A) None of these have any appearance of any sort of root or anything holding it on, and B) None of them are grouped together or growing two at once. They're all stand-alone.

Comment: I'm imagining some isolated spores blew in with the wind and attached. That would essentially illustrate how a colony gets started. Those fruiting bodies will eventually release spores of their own and you'll find more stalks over time (and eventually more features of a mold colony). I'd just use some bleach water and clean it off.

Comment: Now that I think about it, there is some field of fungus growing in the woodchips about 10 feet away. Those ones look a bit more developed, and look like light orange bubbles.

Comment: The ones growing a bit further away look like this: http://my.kwic.com/~pagodavista/schoolhouse/species/plants/pics/fungi3.jpg

Comment: This is definitely not fungus. See a related question [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58192/what-are-these-location-india/58225#58225)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [lacewing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysopidae) eggs. Lacewings lay their eggs on stalks.

From wikipedia  :

[image]

Comment: can you add some sort of reference or other picture for confirmation? Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: From the linked article... "Eggs are deposited at night, singly or in small groups; one female produces some 100–200 eggs. Eggs are placed on plants, usually where aphids are present nearby in numbers. Each egg is hung on a slender stalk about 1 cm long, usually on the underside of a leaf."

Comment: Two differences - they weren't clustered like that, they were scattered - and also they were on windows, at least a few yards away from any vegetation.

Comment: this comment is a little late,but I read about this in a book,then another book,then Buggguide" i think