# What are these (eggs?) ? ( Location - India )

Tags: species-identification, eggs, arthropod

[image]

<sub>*The picture can be zoomed in on clicking*</sub>

**Description:**

There are 24 of them, each ovoid, 1mm long and attached to the switch's frame by suction cups connected by tubes. They are secured to the base and couldn't be brushed off with a stick. Found them in East of India.

***UPDATE***

The ovoid heads have reduced in number (17) and have turned brownish (10.04.2017). The number of ovoid heads are 11 now and two of them have a black spot at the proximal end (could be the eye spots of developing embryos) (13.04.2017). The bunch has 4 of them now (24.04.2017).

**Research & Question:**

Assuming those are eggs <sup>(resemble those of Green lacewing and with the changes observed it is evident)</sup>, what group of arthropods have such stalked eggs other than Green lacewing?

Comment: Appears to be very similar to the specimens in [this SE Post](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/49134/is-this-some-sort-of-fungus/55450#55450)

Comment: Yeah, they do look like eggs (of Green lacewing). In fact they have turned brownish and the number of ovoid structures have decreased which makes me think that they are eggs of some arthropod. @theforestecologist

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The group of insects called *Neuropterans* have several species that lay eggs on stalks. This group includes lacewings, owlflies and antlions, however stalked eggs are not a defining trait of the group. In addition to the Green lacewing, the Blue-eyed lacewing from Australia lays stalked eggs while owlflies do not. [Mantidflies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantispidae) also have stalked eggs which are members of the Neuroptera order, but the stalks are relatively short compared to lacewings.

[This thread](http://bugguide.net/node/view/357112) provides some interesting discussion.

P.S. While not an arthropod, at least one Genus of Molluscs [(*Nucella*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucella), lay stalked eggs too.

These are certainly eggs from this order (Neuroptera). Incubation time for these type of eggs can be anywhere from 2-7 days so you may already be having hatching if there are less eggs than what was initially there.

Comment: You may also like to include the Berothidae, beaded lacewings with those having stalked eggs.