# What are these bulbous-ended filaments?

Tags: species-identification

Yesterday I noticed an array of filament type structures, each with a bulbous feature at the end, hanging off my car door. As can be seen in the first image, these structures are quite small (comparing to door handle/key hole). I live in Kentucky, USA. What are they?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They look like lacewing eggs, though related insects can have similar-looking eggs. [Lacewings](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~dorr/Insects/Predators/Lacewing/green_lacewing_eggs.html) are [beneficial insects](http://tcpermaculture.blogspot.com/2011/05/beneficial-insects-lacewings.html); their eggs are laid on stalks, like this:

[image]

*Edit* to point to other questions and answers here:

- [Is this some sort of fungus?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/49134/is-this-some-sort-of-fungus/55450#55450)
- [What are these (eggs?) ? ( Location - India )](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58192/what-are-these-eggs-location-india)